Integral of $\frac{1}{a + x^2}$
I just finished taking Calculus I and I'm now learning different integration techniques like partial fractions and substitution.
Recently I came to know that because of the reverse chain rule, we have to multiply the integral of a function with 1 / (the derivative of the inside function)
But the formula for (if $x$ isn't a constant or single variable) I saw first was:
$\int\frac{1}{1 + x^2}= \frac{1}{x'} \cdot \arctan(x) + C$
But from the My Organic Chemistry Tutor youtube channel the formula:
$\int\frac{1}{a + u^2} = 
\frac{1}{ a} \cdot \arctan( \frac{u}{ a}) + C $
So which ones are correct and where are they derived from?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

$\int \frac1{a^2+x^2}dx\overset{u=x/a}{=}\int \frac{1}{a^2+a^2u^2}adu=\frac1a\int\frac1{1+u^2}du=\frac1a\arctan(u)+c=\frac1a\arctan(x/a)+c$

Careful: there's a class of substitutions that handle this (which you see in the next course!).

$\dfrac{1}{a+x^2}=
\dfrac{1}{ a}\times\dfrac{1}{1+\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt a}\right)^2}$
